# Why when I use app.use its throwing a 404 on Express app?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm getting a 404 when I want to use 'app.use' to create my routes.

**app.js**

```
const aboutRouter = require('./routes/about');

app.use('/about', aboutRouter);
```

**routes > about.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

/* GET about page. */
router.get('/about', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('about', { title: 'About' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**views > about.hbs**

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
```

These pages below work. Not sure why when I follow the same pattern I'm getting the error.

```
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
```

Comment: What URL 404's? Are you trying to go to `/about` or `/about/about`?

Comment: I want it to go to `/about` not `/about/about`, but it's not rendering the page. Getting a 404 when I view `/about` in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page 404s because the real path of the about page is `/about/about`. You're mounting the router at `/about`, but also serving the about page at `/about` inside the about router. You should instead serve it at `/`:

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

/* GET about page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('about', { title: 'About' });
});

module.exports = router;
```